# How to tackle increase and decrease post in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently a bit stuck in this bit, I'm sure I'm doing something silly (I'm trying also not to repeat myself as i'm fetching posts 3 times, don't kill me I'm new at this), I'm trying to change the number of post via an increase/decrease button scheme. So far I'm causing unnecessary re-renders as well as the counter is off (I've got to click it twice in order to go to the proper post), how can I tackle this? the code is below:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

export const Login = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({});
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchPosts()
    } ,[]);

    const handleIncrease = () => {
        setCounter(counter + 1);
        fetchPosts();
    };

    const handleDecrease = () => {
        setCounter(counter - 1);
        fetchPosts();
    };

    const fetchPosts = () => {
        const options = {
            url: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${counter}`,
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            },
        };

        return (
            axios(options)
                .then((response) => {
                    return setData(response.data)
            })
        )
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleIncrease}>add one</button>
            <button onClick={handleDecrease}>{console.log(data)}Subtract one</button>
        </div>

    )
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'counter is off'? Do you mean that the count value is undefined or 0?

Comment: No, I mean that when I click to increase the counter, the post that I’m fetching only start changing after the second click not on the first.

Comment: i don't know if its correct but i don't think you have to call the fetchPosts() function in the increase and decrease function and instead just pass the counter in the useEffect array so that it calls the function every time the counter changes and gets the latest posts for you and also it might be taking some time to fetch the posts in the first click, so just wait for the process to complete when you click first. I am beginner to react too so just my thoughts, i am not sure if i am correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Try using this code. In this code the useEffect is called each time
>   the counter value changes that means the counter value changes on
>   handleIncrease and handleDecrease function  and also remove the fetch
>   function from handleIncrease and handleDecrease. Also the fetch
>   function is declared before useEffect.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
    import axios from 'axios'

    export const Login = () => {
        const [data, setData] = useState({});
        const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);
       const fetchPosts = () => {
            const options = {
                url: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${counter}`,
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                },
            };

            return (
                axios(options)
                    .then((response) => {
                        return setData(response.data)
                })
            )
        };

        useEffect(() => {
            fetchPosts()
        } ,[counter]);

        const handleIncrease = () => {
            setCounter(counter + 1);
        };

        const handleDecrease = () => {
            setCounter(counter - 1);
        };


        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={handleIncrease}>add one</button>
                <button onClick={handleDecrease}>{console.log(data)}Subtract one</button>
            </div>

        )
    };
```

Comment: Thanks!!! This is what I needed, by any chance would you happen to know how to declare my counter when using componentdidmount() as component did mount doesn’t share the same syntax.

Comment: Call the fetchPosts() function in componentdidmount() {fetchPosts () } first for initial rendering and when the counter value changes call componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.counter !== this.state.counter) {
    fetchPosts ()
  }
}

Comment: You my friend, are worth your weight in gold. Thank you so much.

Comment: You can contact me at anytime for clearing doubts regarding Reactjs. I am always happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is probably something to do with synchronization. Since Axios is asynchronous you probably want to use `async ()` and `await`. When you first click, the GET request is called but your code returns before the GET request does. When you click for a second time the get request has returned and the value is updated. Async "blocks" until the value is returned and then continues execution.

For example, you might want something similar to this.

```
fetchPosts = async () => {
     const options = {
            url: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${counter}`,
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
     },

    let res = await axios.get(options).then((response) => {
                    return setData(response.data)
            })
    return res;
};
```

For reference: https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-use-async-await-with-axios-in-react-e07daac2905f